# Gigabit detection DIY

Tags: ethernet, ac-dc, gigabit

Ethernet up to 100Mbps uses only 2 of the 4 twisted wires in an ethernet cable while gigabit is using all of them. Connecting an LED to one of the gigabit-only pairs should therefore make it easy to detect a gigabit transmission.

Well, actually not. Problem is, that PoE may or may not be used, the ethernet data is AC while an "this is gigabit"-led is DC, ethernet has no fixed current and I have no clue what I'm talking about.

I really ain't versed in electronics. A rectifier between ethernet and the LED would solve the AC problem, but this can't be the whole solution. Ethernet has no fixed voltage as described in [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/what-is-the-voltage-used-in-ethernet-lines-utp-cables). Is there a module that counters fluctuation in a way that the LED gets the power it needs? Even with the low energy from a ethernet cable? If yes, would this work with PoE injection on the unused wirepairs as well?

**Background:** An intrusion detection system based on Microsofts ATA has to have a physical connection to the network so I've built a network tap with a maximum throughput of 100Mbps. I forward only two of the wirepairs, forcing any network clients to use a maximum of 100Mbps. This may obviously cause a giant bottleneck, but while not preventable, I would at least like to know when this is a problem. A litte status LED would be nice, flickering upon gigabit data connection.

First post and glad about criticism. Thanks

Comment: Cables have wires, not veins ...

Comment: Do you mean 100 Mbps rather than what you said (100mb)?

Comment: jep. mbps. Sorry for the veins

Comment: Attaching anything to the data lines will result in signal degradation... What is the point of forcing 100Mbps?

Comment: @MadHatter 1000BASE isn't just 100BASE with higher speeds. Gigabit reads and sends on the same port. A gigabit card knows what it's receiving because it can subtract what it sent from the current on the port. A simple tap can't know that, it would just receive some gibberish. You would have to engage between the clients e.g. thorugh a switch to know what's sent in which direction, but to prevent intruder from noticing the intrusion detection system, taps are designed to read stealth. That's simply not possible for 1000BASE communication, because you would have to reroute packets.

Comment: So, do you mean "m" or "M" (milli or mega). I think I know the answer of course but a certain pride is taken here for unit correctness.

Comment: @Andyaka Huge difference between milli and mega ^^ Edited.

Comment: This question is off-topic because the user has no understanding of RF effects of a non-linear diode capacitance on a balanced RF differential signal, asking for a hopelessly simple solution.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I informed me as best as I can before writing this question, bc I don't want to waste any ones time. If you suggest that I inform me about the "RF effects of a non-linear diode capacitance on a balanced RF differential signal" I'll gladly do that. I wouldn't have asked if I knew everything. As stated, I'm an absolute beginner in electronics, but I'm willing to learn and interested in this topic. So yeah, thanks for the input. I'm going to investigate into these effects. I don't think this forum is for professionals only.

Comment: You cannot attach a diode onto Ethernet port.  Use a software solution like WireShark or  PerfMon

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, thats actually what I'm doing already. But wether wireshark or the intrusion detection system I'm using, they both need to take a look into ongoing network traffic. That's what the tap is for.

Comment: Just monitor the overall traffic rate. If you get above some specified level of congestion (50%? 30%? 10%) you know that restricting the network to 100 Mbps is causing a bottleneck. Of course this doesn't tell you whether the clients on the other end of the wire are gigabit-capable.  And if you were trying to hide the existence of your monitor from gigabit-capable clients, you already did that when you cut the gigabit connection.

Comment: Also enable logging in your router to collect internet noise and email yourself the results when the log is full.  Lots of [Message:1]ATT:001[SYN-ACK][192.168.2.101][LAN-1]  from disconnects from WiFi Rician Fading or network disconnects. Just noise.

Comment: As far as I know, Ethernet only uses two pairs to do link negotiation. I've heard stories of two GigE devices connected through 2-pair UTP, where both devices would (correctly) conclude the other end could do GigE as well, both devices proceeded to switch to full GigE mode using all 4 pairs, and then the link wouldn't work because only 2 pairs were installed. I'm unsure if this is actually true, but it's something to be mindful of.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help. Seems like I have to use a microcontroller in some way. I just thought if mulitmeter could do exact measuring without an rpi, I should be able to get a simple true/false for my LED with just a few parts.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would not work. Even if you ignore completely messing up what is basically an RF link by introducing a nonlinear element, it just has not way to work. You have to monitor actual traffic to do what you want to do.

An ethernet link is basically negotiated at the physical layer when the link is initiated. If the physical layer sees that the two additional pairs cannot be used it would not just try to use them if the link becomes congested.

The additional pairs are not like a overspill gate on a dam. You either have a Gigabit ethernet link or you don't. You either use the extra pairs, or you don't. There is no in-between.